# Saltstack boto_vpc state execution

Tags: cloud, salt-stack

I have the following state in SaltStack that i'm trying to execute in order to create a VPC in AWS.

```
vpc_exists:
  boto_vpc.present:
    - name: saltstack_test_vpc
    - cidr_block: 10.0.0.0/16
    - dns_hostnames: True
    - region: us-east-1
    - keyid: SECRET_KEY_ID
    - key: SECRET_KEY
```

Although the documentation in https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.boto_vpc.html#manage-vpcs says how to create the state, it does not say how to execute it.
What i have not been able to find out, is how to execute this state. Obviously, here i don't have a target system as i have when pushing configuration to a server by doing:  `salt -v 'TARGET_SERVER' state.highstate`

So my question is how can one execute this state or any other boto_vpc states ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install salt-minion into your salt master as well. E.g., let say your saltmaster hostname is `my-salt`, you should see a key appear using `sudo salt-key -L`
2. Accept the key, e.g. `sudo salt-key -a my-salt`
3. Now in your top.sls, create entry that target your own salt-minion my-salt.
4. run highstate against your own minion `sudo salt "my-salt" state.highstate`

you top.sls should looks something like following. And your above code are named as createvpc.sls

```
base:
  "my-salt":
    createvpc
```

Comment: Thank you @mootmoot ! That worked, and so simple. It never crossed my mind to just target a minion that would execute that state.